# Unexpected label, don't understand why

Tags: batch-file

Need some help with my code, when it's run it gives an error message really quickly and then closes. The error is "Unexpected SetPassword1". You'll understand what SetPassword1 is when you see the code.

```
:SetPassword
cls
echo This is where you can set your password or change it.
if EXIST pass.txt (
for /f "Delibs=" %%a in (pass.txt) do (
set OldPass=%%a
set /p OldPassCheck=What was your old password: 
if %OldPassCheck%==%OldPass% goto SetPassword1
echo That's not your old password.
pause
goto MainLogin
)
)
echo.
pause
goto SetPassword1
```

If my code is too stupid to be understood, this is basically what I want it to do;
It's to set a new password if there already is one, or set one if there isn't one already.
So I want it to check if pass.txt (which contains the password) exists or not, and if it does it takes the password from in there. Then it's set to the OldPass. Then it asks the user what the old password was and if it is correct then it would goto SetPassword1 (where you would set the new password), and if it wasn't it would go back to the main menu. And of course if pass.txt didn't exist it wouldn't execute the command(s) in the If and go directly to SetPassword1.

Hope that wasn't too confusing! Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

PS. I know storing passwords in a simple text document isn't safe, but this is just a test application and not something that will actually protect anything.

PS2. A SetPassword1 label does exist, I just didn't include it here. Sorry! :P

Comment: I don't see a label named `SetPassword1` in your code.

Comment: It does, I just didn't include it. Oopsie. Edited the question.

Comment: You have `:SetPassword`, but are doing `goto SetPassword1`, **WITH** the `1`.

Comment: I still don't see a label named `SetPassword1` in your code.  A label is preceded by a colon, as in `:SetPassword`.

Comment: `"Delibs="` -> `"Delims="`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>your `goto` does not find the label `Setpassword1`. Either change the `goto` to `SetPassword` or change your first label to match the identifier `:SetPassword1` or create an appropiate label later in your code.</del>

**EDIT**

you need to **enable delayed expansion** to have `oldpass` variable appropiately update inside the `FOR` code.

```
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  ....

  if !OldPassCheck!==!OldPass! goto SetPassword1
```

Comment: The label setpassword1 does exist, I just didn't include it here. Sorry. Edited the question.